# In template, no type named type in "std::result_of<int&()>"

Tags: c++

i am new to C++ programming, and am confused as to why i cannot supply my template parameters to intialise a packaged_task in cpp.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>
#include <future>

using namespace std::chrono;
using std::future;
using std::packaged_task;
using std::priority_queue;

class CPlayGround {
    priority_queue<int> pq;

public:
    CPlayGround() {
        using task_type = int();
        packaged_task<task_type> pt{aFunc()};
    }

    int aFunc() {
        return 10;
    }
};
```

my CLion compiler states:

> In template, no type named type in "std::result_of<int&()>"

Comment: `aFunc` is **not** of type `int()`.  It is a nonstatic member function, requiring a `this` to be supplied to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`packaged_task` wraps a callable object, if you pass `aFunc()`, you're passing the result of the call, which is an `int`, in your case it's the same as writing:

```
packaged_task<task_type> pt{10}; // does not make much sense, right?
```

If `aFunc` was a free function (not a member-function), you could pass its address to the `packaged_task` constructor:

```
packaged_task<task_type> pt{&aFunc};
```

But since it's a member function, the easiest-way<sup>1</sup> is to wrap the call in a lambda:

```
packaged_task<task_type> pt{[this] { return aFunc(); }};
```

If you're not familiar with the syntax, `[this] { return aFunc(); }` is a lambda which captures `this`, takes no parameters (the `()` is optional for lambda) and whose body is as specified (we can access the member-function `aFunc()` because `this` is captured).

<sub><sup>1</sup> There are other ways, e.g. `std::bind`, but using a capturing lambda is what I would recommend in most cases.</sub>

Comment: @Duwang If you have a new problem, open a new question, it'll be easier for you to explain your problem.